# How can I load a library in Codeigniter via autoload composer?

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, autoload

I have installed autoload via composer in CodeIgniter and I also tested it if the file `autoload.php` is included and it's. So, if i have a library called `Pager` in libraries, then how can I instantiate (load) the `Pager` class? It's a fresh CodeIgniter installation, version 3.1.2

I set in config this:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

I have try the following ways in Welcome controller:

```
$pager = new libraries\Pager();  //Class 'libraries\Pager' not found 
$pager = new \libraries\Pager(); //Class 'libraries\Pager' not found
$pager = new \library\Pager();   // Class 'library\Pager' not found
$pager = new Pager();            // Class 'library\Pager' not found
```

And here is the Pager class from libraries directory:

```
class Pager  {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo __CLASS__;
    }

}
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2):

This is in fact unrelated to CodeIgniter.

You need to tell `composer` that you have your own PHP classes that aren't among autoloaded files.

In your `composer.json` add one of these:

```
{
    // ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "MyNamespace\\": "src/library/MyNamespace" },
        "files": ["src/some/custom/filepath.php"]
    }
}
```

Then run in console `update` to update `autoload.php` with your new config:

```
$ composer update
```

Now every time you use a class from `MyNamespace` such as `MyNamespace\MyClass` it'll look for file `src/library/MyNamespace/MyClass.php`.
Also, file `src/some/custom/filepath.php` is always included automatically so you don't need to include it manually. (I don't know what's your usecase).

See for more info: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

Answer (score 1):

Do you have added it in autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array(
'pager'
);
```